# Is there something like Flipboard for normal browsers?

Tags: webapp-rec

So we have this awesome Flipboard App on the iPad now... or Zite.com to add another one to the game. I don't own an iPad yet I have social profiles everywhere full of awesome news streams that I would LOVE to read in a beautiful way.

Is there any Flipboard clone that does intelligently present the most relevant news to me in a browser, not an iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Feedly](http://www.feedly.com/)?

It is linked to Google Reader feeds and includes your personal twitter feed as well. You can also customize layouts, from lists to galery views, look for suggestions, save articles for later and get recommendations.

I don't think it is available for IE but you can find it for Chrome, Firefox, iPhone and now Android.

Answer (score 0):

I use [tweetedtimes.com](http://tweetedtimes.com) and [paper.li](http://paper.li) to create an interactive newspaper from my twitter feed. But feedly is cool too 'cause it supports greader.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can try this app for Google Chrome:

[PurpleGene Feed Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lgjiekambmjckfnbedchbjiamngedppn)

Hit the "Enter" key when page loads to see a newspaper-like UI